# on Angular 10, When i have Modal over Modal, BsModalRef hide method hides both popups and leave dark background make App unusable

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, angular10, ngx-bootstrap-modal

I have 2 ng-Template and first modal is opening the other one. When I hide the top modal it hides the below one also and only leaves black background and app is unusable, i have to manually refresh the browser. This was working fine before we upgraded to angular 7 to 10.

import { BsModalService , BsModalRef} from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

```js
 closeTestPopup1()
  {
    this.modalRef.hide();
  }

  openpopup2(template)
  {
    this.modalRef2 = this.modalService.show(template, { class: 'mrk-def-modal approve-task-modal modal-dialog-centered' });
  }

  closeTestPopup2()
  {
    this.modalRef2.hide();
  }
```

```html
<ng-template #TestPopup1>
    <div class="btn-row mt-3 d-none d-md-flex">
      <button i18n matRipple class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm ml-auto" type="button" (click)="closeTestPopup1()">
        Cancel
      </button>
      <button i18n matRipple class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ml-2 set-s-bg-color"  (click)="openpopup2(TestPopup2)"
        >
        Save
      </button>
    </div>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template #TestPopup2>
    <div class="btn-row mt-3 d-none d-md-flex">
      <button i18n matRipple class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm ml-auto" type="button" (click)="closeTestPopup2()">
        Cancel popup 2
      </button>
      <button i18n matRipple class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ml-2 set-s-bg-color" type="submit"
        >
        Save
      </button>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

Comment: This is a (known) issue with newer versions of ngx-bootstrap. Try an older version and it should work again..

Comment: Thanks @MikeOne , its really helpful, I downgraded from 6.1 to 6.0 and it worked, can you please refer e to exact issue link , I couldn't find it.

Comment: i upgraded to 6.2 and it also worked there. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it was ngx-bootstrap issue ..upgrading it to latest version fixed it.